# ASP.NET MVC and custom authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using `[Authorize]` and `[Authorize(Roles = "User")]` attributes in my ASP.NET MVC controllers, so when I'm not in "User" role `[Authorize(Roles = "User")]` redirect me to login page. Now website have about 10 different roles and for each one I need to redirect to different page. My idea for this was to write own `Attribute`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorize : FilterAttribute
{
    public CustomAuthorize(string role)
    {
       ...            
    }
}
```

But how can I check `User.Identity` in this attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can access it from:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use a Filter, you could use the [`OnActionExecuting()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx) method, which will provide a `filterContext` parameter that can be used to resolve your current user :

```
public class CustomAuthorize : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Use the context to access the user 
        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;

        if(user != null)
        {
            // Check your role and redirect accordingly here
            var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.Identity.Name);

            // Grab the first role (example)
            var role = roles.FirstOrDefault();

            // Based on the users role, do something
            switch(role)
            {
                 case "Administrator":
                       // Handle your redirect here
                       filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("Admin", routeValues);
                 break;
                 default:
                       // Do nothing, allow to pass through as usual
                 break;
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Likewise, you could make your `CustomAuthorize` class inherit from the base `AuthorizeAttribute`, then you could use the the [`AuthorizeCore()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore(v=vs.118).aspx) method that is exposed which already has a parameter for your current context to handle what to do :

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // Access your current user from the context
        var user = httpContext.User;

        // Do stuff here


        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```